# Bash :Adding Output of command to an existing array

Tags: bash

I have Array of 3 elements and I retrieve these elements in for loop and perform some command on it.

and I want to store the output in single array. How can I do that?

*Array1* contains

```
[ /home/users/abc  /home/users/pqr  /home/users/xyz]
```

I want to perform

```
declare -a product_array
IFS=":"
read -ra ADDR <<< "$Array1" 
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
  DIR=${i}/aaa/deployment/traces/    
  product_array=( $(product_array) $(ls $DIR)  )
done
```

I want to store everything in `product_array`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
$(product_array)
```

is completely wrong here; it will try to run `product_array` as a command and interpolate its output ([command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)). You are looking for

```
"${product_array[@]}"
```

which interpolates the array of this name with proper quoting.

Though you should also avoid the [undesired or outright dangerous side effects of the `ls` command](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); on the whole, you seem to simply want

```
for dir in "${Array1[@]}"; do
    product_array+=("$dir"/*)
done
```

You should also avoid upper case for your private variable names; all-uppercase is reserved for system variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still fairly new to arrays in Bash, but I just got this to work without a for loop

```
a="1 2 3 4"
b="a b c d"
test=($(echo $a))
echo ${test[*]}

1 2 3 4

test+=($(echo $b))
echo ${test[*]}

1 2 3 4 a b c d
```

Comment: That is, however, not what OP was asking.